# linear equation with two different value for all variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

i have 8 equations and 8 variables

```
a+c=8
d+e+f=12
g+h+z=12
a+d+g=12
e+h=8
c+f+z=12
a+e+z=12
c+e+g=12
```

and i have two list of value for all variables :

first results:

```
a=8      
c=0
d=-4
e=4
f=12
g=8
h=4
z=0
```

second results:

```
a=3
c=5
d=6
e=4
f=2
g=3
h=4
z=5
```

if you set value of first result or second result in equation both of them are correct is that possible?!

because if i have 6 equations and 6 variable i should have **only and only one value** for a variable(that mean i should have one result list for equation not two) is that right?

Comment: If the determinant of system not zero then one solution, but if det zero not guaranteed.

Comment: @coffeemath  can you give me an example of two variable and two equation with twolist of result?

Comment: @mehranarbabian $x+y=1$ and $2x+2y=2$

Comment: @mehranarbabian Here is the [general solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=system+a%2Bc%3D8%2C+d%2Be%2Bf%3D12%2C+g%2Bh%2Bz%3D12%2C+a%2Bd%2Bg%3D12%2C+e%2Bh%3D8%2C+c%2Bf%2Bz%3D12%2C+a%2Be%2Bz%3D12%2C+c%2Be%2Bg%3D12).

Comment: Mehran-- see gimusi's comment for a simple 2 by 2 example.

Comment: The first three equations added together are the same as the next three equations added together. So the first 6 equations are linearly dependent, and any one of them can be deduced from the other 5. So really you only have 7 equations for the 8 unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check all calculation but if it is correct it means that some of the equation are dependent and thus the system has infinitely many solutions.

See also the related

- [How to calculate a general solution to a linear system from a kernel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2668098/505767)

Comment: @mehranarbabian e.g. $x+y=1$ and $2x+2y=2$. Try to construct the matrix for your system and find the rank.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if you sum up the first 3 equation then substract the following 3, you get 0=0. The system of equations is therefore not invertible (one of the first six equations is superfluous, so you have 7 equations and 8 variables), hence there can be more than one solution.

Comment: That's right and we can say that when we can find at least 2 solutions then infinitely many solutions exist.